# No matching function for call, but never called that exact function

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I keep getting this error : no matching function for call to 'Dog::Dog()

It says I'm giving 0 arguments and there is no corresponding function. But in fact, I am providing 1 argument like I intended on doing and the error still prevails to show up.

I made a temporary fix by creating a constructor that took no arguments and just initialized the dogs name to ***""***.

**my Dog class**

```
class Dog{
    string name;
public:
    Dog( string vName );
    string getName() { return name; }
};
```

**Everything that initializes a Dog**

- **Human Class**

```
class Human{
    Dog myDog;
    string name;
    int age;
public:
```

- **Human Constructors**

• Default Constructor

```
Human::Human(){
    name = "undefined";
    age = 0;
    myDog = Dog("Jimmy");
}
```

• OverLoaded Constructor 1

```
Human::Human(string vName, int vAge){
    name = vName;
    age = vAge;
    myDog = Dog("Jimmy");
}
```

• OverLoaded Constructor 2

```
Human::Human(string vName, int vAge, Dog vDog){
   age = vAge;
   name = vName;
   myDog = vDog;
}
```

As you can see, nothing initializes a dog with just Dog(). Everything initializes dog with a string as parameter 1.

Comment: You're not initialising anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Human`'s constructors you are trying to initialize a `Dog` object with a default constructor that does not exists. This happens because when you reach the constructor body, all the member variables should be already constructed. If you don't use an [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html), the constructor chosen is the default one (which does not exists for the class `Dog`).

You can fix that by using an initialization list like follows:

```
Human::Human()
    : name("undefined")
    , age(0)
    , myDog("Jimmy")
    {}

Human::Human(string vName, int vAge)
    : name(vName)
    , age(vAge)
    , myDog("Jimmy")
    {}

Human::Human(string vName, int vAge, Dog vDog)
    : name(vName)
    , age(vAge)
    , myDog(vDog)
    {}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your answer. Just before this problem occurred I was doing research on initialization lists but couldn't find anything good on them. This gives me a better understanding of them. Also a special thanks for the link explaining them a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

In class `Human` on this line:

```
Dog myDog;
```

You do create a dog with the default constructor, so that's where it's called from.

In the `Human` constructor you do set `myDog`:

```
myDog = Dog("Jimmy");
```

That will expand into two steps:

- Create a new temporary `Dog` object by calling the `Dog(string)` constructor.
- Call the assignment operator of `Dog` to assign the temporary object to the object contained in the `Human` class.

What you probably want to do is to call a specific constructor for the `myDog` field from the `Human` constructor instead:

```
Human::Human(): myDog("Jimmy") {
    name = "undefined";
    age = 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that really what happens? I thought those didn't get initialized until you store a value in them. That's why they're left undefined in the body of the class right?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you define it as a contained object it is created before the constructor body is entered. If you want it to be clear until you store a value you have to use a pointer instead (which brings in the whole memory management issue)

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! I especially love two things: how you broke it down into steps and explained what happened, and also liked that you only left what was necessary in the initialization list giving me a better understanding on how they could be used.

Answer (score 0):

In this definition of the class

```
class Human{
    Dog myDog;
    string name;
    int age;
public:
```

for creating object myDog the default constructor of class Dog is called. However you did not define the default constructor in this class. So the compiler issues the error.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ instance variables that are classes are constructed **before** your class's constructor is called.  This is done by calling the classes default constructor.  That is where the initialization is coming from.

This can be fixed by using [initializer list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/) syntax in your `Human` constructor:

```
Human::Human() : myDog("Jimmy") {  
    name = "undefined";
    age = 0;
}
```